# Native function [.sort()] not recognized inside event handler

Tags: javascript, typeerror, worker

**Environment: SeaMonkey (FireFox 20.0)**

I'm trying to do a simple sort: **Either** inside a worker itself OR inside its postMessage handler.

(All code samples from inside the top level (.html) file).

**works:**

```
function a() {
  var xyzzy = [40, 1, 5, 200];
  xyzzy.sort();
};
```

**fails**: (Error: TypeError: xyzzy.sort is not a function)

```
var lrw0 = new Worker('lrw0.js');
lrw0.onmessage = function (event) {
  var xyzzy = [40, 1, 5, 200];
  xyzzy.sort();
};
```

After the postMessage event the handler has the same context and scope as did the worker. Fair enough. Needless to say the sort fails inside the worker itself. Seems as if a utility library cannot be accessed?

Utterly defeated. I have spent days on this - no doubt reading the solution somewhere without having understood it. Any contributions (including 'rude but informative') gratefully accepted. I fully appreciate the necessity of mercilessly punishing newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those examples will work until you fix the call to the [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

> Syntax
>
> array.sort([compareFunction])

Javascript

```
function a() {
  var xyzzy = [40, 1, 5, 200];
  xyzzy.sort(); // notice the difference

  console.log(xyzzy);
};

a();
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Q2rYH/)

Comment: I have edited the original question to correctly reflect my test cases. [ie changed .sort to .sort();]  So thank-you for spotting that Xotic750 but now back to square one. As I say one case works and the identical case in a different context fails.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your issue, for a start I do not have a copy of "lrw0.js". You need to help us to help you.

Comment: Thank-you again Xotic750. I created a new 'lrw0.js' file containing a single line: "onmessage = function (event) {postMessage('');}" and now the sort works in both contexts. I will incrementally re-instate the removed logic until the error re-occurs and be sure to post the results. I will try and flag this closed until then.